# Phonegap Plugin Activity Import Layout

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova Plugin that has an Activity, and I need to access the application R.layout from this activity so I can call `setContentView`.

I'm currently doing this by making an `import com.example.hello.R` and then on the `onCreate method I call`setContentView(R.layout.mysurfaceview)`:

The problem is that my plugin will only work if the application name is `com.example.hello`, but I need to install my plugin on different applications without manually making the imports.

Is there a way to make a generic import, something like `import <appName>.R`, or any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could call the application's resource pool at runtime and refer to the identifier by name using the [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) function. This function needs the resource name, type, and package name. For example:

```
 String package_name = getApplication().getPackageName();
 Resources resources = getApplication().getResources();
 setContentView(resources.getIdentifier("my_activity_layout", "layout", package_name));
```

where "my_activity_layout" is the name of the layout xml file. You can also refer to strings, drawables, and other resources in the same fashion. Once you have that bit of code in your activity, you can designate your activity layout file as a source file in your plugin.xml file and set it to be copied into the res/layout folder.

```
<source-file src="path/to/your/layout/file.xml" target-dir="res/layout"/>
```

Check out the [Phonegap Plugin Specification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification) if you have any other questions about using the source-file designation.

Comment: I think that a hook is way too complicated for this and may not work with phonegap build. Using resources.getIdentifier works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [cordova CLI hook](https://leanpub.com/developingwithcordovacli/read#hooks-chapter) to modify the java import statement at build time, perhaps by parsing the name of the package out of the AndroidManifest or config.xml.

I don't believe there's a way to do a wildcard package import like you are asking about.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I'm facing the same issues here!

Comment: @Sebastian, did you try writing a hook?

Comment: :No actually I've never done this before... Can you give me a hint where to start? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mooreds's answer,
You can create an `after_plugin_install` hook in your plugin like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/*
A hook to add R.java to the draw activiy in Android platform.
*/


var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var rootdir = process.argv[2];

function replace_string_in_file(filename, to_replace, replace_with) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    var result = data.replace(to_replace, replace_with);
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, result, 'utf8');
}

var target = "stage";
if (process.env.TARGET) {
    target = process.env.TARGET;
}

    var ourconfigfile = path.join( "plugins", "android.json");
    var configobj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ourconfigfile, 'utf8'));
  // Add java files where you want to add R.java imports in the following array

    var filestoreplace = [
        "platforms/android/src/in/co/geekninja/plugin/SketchActivity.java"
    ];
    filestoreplace.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
        if (fs.existsSync(val)) {
          console.log("Android platform available !");
          //Getting the package name from the android.json file,replace with your plugin's id
          var packageName = configobj.installed_plugins["in.co.geekninja.Draw"]["PACKAGE_NAME"];
          console.log("With the package name: "+packageName);
          console.log("Adding import for R.java");
            replace_string_in_file(val,"package in.co.geekninja.plugin;","package in.co.geekninja.plugin;\n\nimport "+packageName+".R;");

        } else {
            console.log("No android platform found! :(");
        }
    });
```

And add the following line between `<platform name="android"> ... </platform>` tag

```
<hook type="after_plugin_install" src="hooks/after_plugin_install/hook-add-r-import.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As @insomniac stated, hooks can be used to replace source file contents to remove wrong imports and/or add the right imports of resources.

Based on his answer, I could create a script that do it without needing to specify the files. It tries to find source files (with *.java* extension), removes any resource import already in it and then put the right resources import (if needed), using the Cordova application package name.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/*
 * A hook to add resources class (R.java) import to Android classes which uses it.
 */

function getRegexGroupMatches(string, regex, index) {
    index || (index = 1)

    var matches = [];
    var match;
    if (regex.global) {
        while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
            matches.push(match[index]);
            console.log('Match:', match);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (match = regex.exec(string)) {
            matches.push(match[index]);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

module.exports = function (ctx) {
    // If Android platform is not installed, don't even execute
    if (ctx.opts.cordova.platforms.indexOf('android') < 0)
        return;

    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
        path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
        Q = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q');

    var deferral = Q.defer();

    var platformSourcesRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android/src');
    var pluginSourcesRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.plugin.dir, 'src/android');

    var androidPluginsData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'plugins', 'android.json'), 'utf8'));
    var appPackage = androidPluginsData.installed_plugins[ctx.opts.plugin.id]['PACKAGE_NAME'];

    fs.readdir(pluginSourcesRoot, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error when reading file:', err)
            deferral.reject();
            return
        }

        var deferrals = [];

        files.filter(function (file) { return path.extname(file) === '.java'; })
            .forEach(function (file) {
                var deferral = Q.defer();

                var filename = path.basename(file);
                var file = path.join(pluginSourcesRoot, filename);
                fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function (err, contents) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error when reading file:', err)
                        deferral.reject();
                        return
                    }

                    if (contents.match(/[^\.\w]R\./)) {
                        console.log('Trying to get packages from file:', filename);
                        var packages = getRegexGroupMatches(contents, /package ([^;]+);/);
                        for (var p = 0; p < packages.length; p++) {
                            try {
                                var package = packages[p];

                                var sourceFile = path.join(platformSourcesRoot, package.replace(/\./g, '/'), filename)
                                if (!fs.existsSync(sourceFile)) 
                                    throw 'Can\'t find file in installed platform directory: "' + sourceFile + '".';

                                var sourceFileContents = fs.readFileSync(sourceFile, 'utf8');
                                if (!sourceFileContents) 
                                    throw 'Can\'t read file contents.';

                                var newContents = sourceFileContents
                                    .replace(/(import ([^;]+).R;)/g, '')
                                    .replace(/(package ([^;]+);)/g, '$1 import ' + appPackage + '.R;');

                                fs.writeFileSync(sourceFile, newContents, 'utf8');
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (ex) {
                                console.log('Could not add import to "' +  filename + '" using package "' + package + '". ' + ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                deferrals.push(deferral.promise);
            });

        Q.all(deferrals)
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Done with the hook!');
                deferral.resolve();
            })
    });

    return deferral.promise;
}
```

Just add as an *after_plugin_install* hook (for Android platform) in your *plugin.xml*:

```
<hook type="after_plugin_install" src="scripts/android/addResourcesClassImport.js" />
```

Hope it helps someone!